# Conceptual question about taxonomy structure

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

Imagine i want a directory of different organisations in different locations. Let's say i have

- hospitals
- retirement homes
- yogashops
- health-insurance agencies
- (...)

in

- Boston
- Detroit
- Denver

I would create an overview listing of the cities to link them to the organistaions-categories of each city. These would be links to a view of all organisations of the chosen type in the chosen city.

What i already have is a vocabulary "organisations" and a vocabulary "cities". I have created a view with a contextual filter "organisations" which lists all items of an organisation-term:

organisations/yogashops

But how can i prepend the selection of a specific city?

Do i have to create a vocabulary of organisations for every city? Even if they are the same?

How can i reuse my "organisations"-vocabulary?

EDIT: Would it be an alternative to create a node for each city and then use them as entity reference for the categories?

Comment: I'd create a node type with both vocabularies in it. Then I'd create a custom view showing list of organizations in each city(assume city is selected) collecting them from the eligible nodes.

Comment: @AgA - Putting your answers in the answer form below allows it to be picked by op as *THE* answer. ;) Allows others to upvote your answer, giving you some oh-precious karma. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: Volker did I understand your question correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you want to prepend the city name as an argument on the view, so you would have:

> organisations/denver/yogashops

well you could equally have the city appended:

> organisations/yogashops/denver

The question has no mention of Views, but I would recommend that you create a view with the contextual filters of organisation and city:
[image: Two contextual filters]

I recently set up something similar for global dealerships /find-a-dealer/europe/fr

Comment: Actually i want the city first, like: denver/yogashops/smith. But i guess this will work as well with views and contextual filters?

Answer (score 0):

can't you just add a second contextual filter to your view, for cities,
and use the thrid url parameter as input ?